# Cannot MATCH WHERE clause on numeric - have to convert with TOSTRING()

Tags: neo4j

I have a database of Tweets.

If I return a Tweet as follows

```
MATCH (t:Tweet) WHERE ID(t) = 337314 RETURN TOSTRING(t.id), ID(t) AS id, t.text AS text
```

I get:

```
657066610235154432  337314  THE WEEK THAT WAS Happenings in #climatechange #politics, #policy &amp; #science for @climaterealitya #reality Website: https://t.co/abnpfO4blb
```

If I then use the property t.id to match the Tweet this fails:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet) WHERE t.id = 657066610235154432 RETURN TOSTRING(t.id), ID(t) AS id, t.text AS text, t.alpha_updated
```

Returns - No Rows

If I use TOSTRING() to convert t.id to string then the node is returned:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet) WHERE TOSTRING(t.id) = '657066610235154432' RETURN TOSTRING(t.id), ID(t) AS id, t.text AS text
```

Here is a screenshot of this in neo4j: http://www.screencast.com/t/EtMSlKdZPv

This is happening on approx 6k of the Tweets from a database of several million. They are in an almost continuous block of ID values, so I suspect a corrupt index during a certain time when these nodes were being added.

Any help understanding and resolving this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: This has to do with the fact that json doesn't support 64 bits integers, you need to convert to string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your DB is sometimes storing a string value for the `id` property.

[Here is a console](http://console.neo4j.org/r/1wug86) that contains 2 nodes with the `id` property. One node uses a string value, and the other uses an integer. The console shows that a `TOSTRING()` query matches both nodes.

However,  if you use this query, you will successfully get (only) the node that stored an integer value:

```
MATCH (t:Tweet)
WHERE t.id = 657066610235154432
RETURN t.id, ID(t) AS id, t.text AS text;
```

Therefore, you need to go through your DB and re-set all properties that have a string value with the corresponding integer value.